# cakephp find list array conditions

Tags: cakephp

I need to filter the results to an array, but I get the following notice

Notice (8): Array to string conversion [APP / Model / User.php, line 199] 
Notice (8): Undefined variable: Array [APP / Model / User.php, line 199]

```
$hotelsId = ClassRegistry::init('HotelUser')->find('all',array('fields'=>array('hotel_id'),'conditions'=>array('user_id'=>$userId)));
        $ids = array();
        foreach ($hotelsId as $hotel) {
            $ids[] = $hotel['HotelUser']['hotel_id'];
        }
        $hotels = ClassRegistry::init('Hotel')->find('list',array('conditions'=>array('IN'=>array('Hotel.id'=>$ids))));
```

Comment: Don't use `'IN'`. Just pass the array as if it were just a single id. Cake will add the `IN` statement magically

Comment: When posting notices and errors, please indicate which line of your code corresponds to the error. In this code, I assume Line 199 is the `foreach()` line. Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks Eagle and George, delete 'In' and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $hotelsId = ClassRegistry::init('HotelUser')->find('list',array(
                                  'fields'=>array('hotel_id'),
                                  'conditions'=>array('user_id'=>$userId)));
    $hotels = ClassRegistry::init('Hotel')->find('list',array(
                                  'conditions'=>array('Hotel.id'=>$hotelsId)));
```

Hope this will help!